# VMWare Fusion 3 MacBook Pro: Trackpad not working

Tags: macbook, vmware-fusion, touchpad

I'm running the trial of Fusion 3 using Windows 2003 and the trackpad just won't work. I've updated VMWare Tools and still no trackpad. Anyone else run into this? I'm in need of a workaround or it's back to Fusion 2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried completely removing the vmware tools, restarting the VM and then proceeding to reinstall it from scratch?

Also, if there are issues with windows 2003, you might want to check VMware forums for any specific detail.